# What exactly does logrotate do to apache log files? (apache 2.4 - ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, apache2.4, logrotate

Other than a couple of basic VHOST's, I have default apache and apache logging configuration. 
Whenever I try to view my apache log files (error.log, access.log) I see that these files keep getting reordered and reorganised regularly, unfortunately I don't understand what the reason or methodology of this is.

From what I have read this log file manipulation is performed by a utility called "logrotate".
with a description from the manpage

> logrotate  is  designed to ease administration of systems that generate
>   large numbers of log files.  It allows automatic rotation, compression,
>   removal, and mailing of log files.  Each log file may be handled daily,
>   weekly, monthly, or when it grows too large.

I have read the following resources:

- http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/understanding-logrotate-utility
- http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-apache-on-an-ubuntu-vps
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#rotation

The above resources give a good technical explanation of how you would *configure* logrotate, but I'm failing to get a common sense explanation of what the *point of log rotate is*, and therefore some insight into how it works.
I can see that it performs compression on some files, the benefit of that is obvious.

I understand that logrotate is a generic utility that processes log files for many services - and therefore its function changes per each config - but, in the context of apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 what does "logrotate" do?

#### Update:

I found this [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxLogFiles) which I found gave a good common sense explanation of what logrotate does and hopefully may help others who come across this question.

> When viewing directory listings in /var/log or any of its
>   subdirectories, you may encounter log files with names such as
>   daemon.log.0, daemon.log.1.gz, and so on. What are these log files?
>   They are 'rotated' log files. That is, they have automatically been
>   renamed after a predefined time-frame, and a new original log started.
>   After even more time the log files are compressed with the gzip
>   utility as in the case of the example daemon.log.1.gz. The purpose of
>   log rotation is to archive and compress old logs so that they consume
>   less disk space, but are still available for inspection as needed.
>   What handles this functionality? Why, the logrotate command of course!

Comment: Cross site post [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188770/68757)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a service that writes a log file, let's say `service.log`, the `logrotate` utility does a couple of things:

1. Start a new (empty) file `service.log` every day;
2. Compress the last `service.log` to a .gz file so it doesn't take up too much space; the new compressed file gets an index number appended, like service.log.gz.00001;
3. The oldest compressed `service.log.gz.[index]` is deleted.

This way, you can run your service indefinitely without the logs ever growing. All of the above behaviour is configurable.

Comment: helpful answer, thanks. the files [index] number seem to have the ordering where the lower the number = most recent. Does that mean that each [index] is  incrementally shifted to the next file on each "rotation"?

Comment: I just checked: in my Apache2 server, a new file is created whenever the log file reaches a certain size (instead of every day) and gets an index number that is one higher than the maximum. Existing zip files are not renamed.

Comment: My behaves differently -obviously different configs. It seems apache will generate a new log every 7 days, regardless of size, and depending on traffic, some are big, some tiny. the `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2` has the lines `weekly missingok     rotate 52`