# Deleting the access.log file or removing its contents in Ubuntu server

Tags: server

I have a website which is hosted on a Ubuntu 12.10 operating system. The problem I am facing these days is, My website goes down often and often.
 When i tried to find the issue, it was in the size of my disk which is around 97% used.
When i ran the command,
 `find / -type f -size +50M -exec du -h {} \; | sort -n`

 I got some information in which the **size of access.log file is 4.5 GB**
Can I delete the access.log file in order to free up some space on my disk or is there any way to compress?

Comment: Heard about `logrotate`? Anyway as it stands, this is an X-Y problem..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly does logrotate do to apache log files? (apache 2.4 - ubuntu 14.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/593910/what-exactly-does-logrotate-do-to-apache-log-files-apache-2-4-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: As a new user in Ubuntu, i have no idea about how to use or add logrotate using the SSH, can you please assist for the same?

Comment: If i am not wrong, its the `/etc/logrotate.conf` file where i have to put the rotation code. For example, `/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is the log file, Clear this file.